# Javascript - Using compose with reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning functional programming with javascript. I have learned that 2 parameters are needed for reduce. Accumalator and the actual value and if we don't supply the initial value, the first argument is used. but I can't understand how the `purchaseItem` functions is working in the code below. can anyone please explain.

```
const user = {
    name: 'Lachi',
    active: true,
    cart: [],
    purchases: []
}
let history = []
const compose = (f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args))

console.log(purchaseItem(
    emptyCart, 
    buyItem, 
    applyTaxToItems, 
    addItemToCart
)(user, {name: 'laptop', price: 200}))

function purchaseItem(...fns) {
    console.log(fns)
    return fns.reduce(compose)
}

function addItemToCart (user, item) {
    history.push(user)
    const updatedCart = user.cart.concat(item)
    return Object.assign({}, user, { cart: updatedCart })
}

function applyTaxToItems(user) {
    history.push(user)
    const {cart} = user
    const taxRate = 1.3
    const updatedCart = cart.map(item => {
        return {
            name: item.name,
            price: item.price * taxRate
        }
    })
    return Object.assign({}, user, { cart: updatedCart })
}

function buyItem(user) {
    history.push(user)
    return Object.assign({}, user, { purchases: user.cart })
}

function emptyCart(user) {
    history.push(user)
    return Object.assign({}, user, {cart: []})
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct `compose` function (did you add the {} when adding console.log() to the inner function)?

Comment: Indeed, a composed function that doesn't return the output of the composition isn't going to be very useful here. Good spot @NickParsons

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for pointing.. I have updated the code with the correct function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a way of creating a pipeline of functions whereby the output from one function is used as the parameter of the next, so we end up with a composed function that is effectively

```
(...args) => 
    emptyCart( 
        buyItem( 
            applyTaxToItems( 
                addItemToCart(...args) 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

Writing the reduce out in longhand might help in understanding:

```
fns.reduce((acc, currentFn) => compose(acc, currentFn))
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it helps if you take a minimal working example and visualize the output structure:

```js
const comp = (f, g) => x => f(g(x));

const inc = x => `inc(${x})`;
const sqr = x => `sqr(${x})`;
const id = x => `id(${x})`;

const main = [sqr, inc, inc, inc].reduce(comp, id);

console.log(main(0)); // id(sqr(inc(inc(inc(0)))))
```

Please note that we need `id` to allow redicung an empty array.

Comment: To the point. made the working of the function very claer